# Question about random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider $X_1, X_2, X_3$ ... random variables i.i.d. such that  $P(X_i=1)=p$ and  $P(X_i=-1)=1-p$. Consider the random walk $(S_n)_{n\ge 0} $ with $S_0=0$ and for $n\ge 1 $,  $S_n = \displaystyle\sum^{n}_{i=1} X_i$. Let $d=2p-1=E X_i$ be the drift of $S_n $. Assume  that  $d>0.$

Define $T_x= \inf \{n\ge0; S_n=x\} $. I want to prove that 
 $\displaystyle\sup_{y>0}\{T_y-\frac {2(y-1)}{d}\}$ is finite.
It's clear that $T_y $ is finite, because $S_n$ is transient to right, but I can not control the difference. I thought of using the fact that the time the walker needs to go from $0$ to $y$ is of the ordem of $\frac {y}{d}$ since d is intuitively the speed of the random walk. Help?

Comment: You can show that $ET_y=\frac{y}{d}$. If you can argue that $\lim_{y \to \infty} T_y/ET_y = 1$ a.s., then you are done. This is sort of like a strong law of large numbers.

Comment: (Note that $ET_y=y/d$ is a nontrivial fact, it does not simply follow from the drift being $d$.)

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the bounty. 1. By the usual one step-decomposition, $E(T_1)=1/d$. 2. By the Markov property, the sequence $(T_y-T_{y-1})_{y>0}$ is i.i.d. and distributed as $T_1$. 3. By the law of large numbers applied to the i.i.d. sequence $(T_y-T_{y-1})_{y>0}$, $T_y/y\to1/d$ almost surely when $y\to\infty$. 4. For every real valued sequence $(t_y)$ such that $t_y/y\to c$ when $y\to\infty$ and for every $(a,b)$ such that $a>c$, $\sup\limits_{y>0}(t_y-ay-b)$ is finite. 5. When $d>0$, $2/d>1/d$. QED.

Answer (score 2):

$S_{T_x + n} - x = S_{T_x + n} - S_{T_x}$ are independent and distributed and $S_n = S_n - S_0$. Thus, $T_{x+1} - T_x$ are independent and distributed as $T_1$. Thus $\frac{T_{y}}{y}$ converges almost surely to $E[T_1]=\frac{1}{d}$ almost surely, according to the Law of Large Numbers. Thus $T_y - \frac{2(y - 1)}{d} = \frac{y}{d} - \frac{2(y-1)}{d} +o(y) = o(y) - \frac{y+1}{d}$ almost surely. Thus $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}$ almost surely $\exists y_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall y > y_0$ $T_y - \frac{2(y - 1)}{d} < c$. That results in $T_y - \frac{2(y - 1)}{d}$ being bounded.